# Do this to core data: "Select * WHERE "attribute" == "Some string" "

Tags: ios, swift

I did manage to do this by making a function with a loop that checks the attribute to a string. But i'm looking for a better way to do this.

**In sql I do this:**

> Select * WHERE "attribute" == "string"

Is there a method to do this in swift?

My function looks like this:

```
func tableData()
{
    let objects = retrieveValues("JobTime") //Retrieve a NSMutableArray
    if !objects.isEmpty
    {
        for var index = 0; index < objects.count; ++index
        {
            if objects[index].valueForKey("jobTitle") as? String == transferTitle
            {
                print("Job title matched: \(index)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Nothing here!")
            }
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Did you have a look at `NSPredicate` and the ["Predicate Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html)? See also ["Fetching Objects"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html) in the Core Data Programming Guide, there is a section "Filtering Results".

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to perform fetch request in CoreData you have to initialise `NSFetchRequest` class. In order to specify in what kind of entities you are interested you create `NSPredicate` class. It gives you ability to specify pretty advanced queries. In most cases the simplest way to create NSPredicate is by using format string - details about the syntax can be found [Apple's Predicate Format String Syntax document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

You can find example of how you can perform fetch request in CoreData (and Swift) below.

```
let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "jobTitle == %@", "Programmer")

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "People")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
//fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [] //optionally you can specify the order in which entities should ordered after fetch finishes

let results = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can pass the query to CoreData and only retrieve what you want. The `NSManagedObjectContext` class has a `executeFetchRequest` method that you call to retrieve data from the database. You pass `NSFetchRequest` object to it. That object contains a `NSPredicate`, which defines your query.